# insert values into temp tables very slow on bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

For some reason it takes BigQuery almost a minute to insert 6 rows into a temporary table. Just the null value insert took BQ 20 seconds.

Example:

```
create temporary table units (
  id string,
  Nof_units int,
  source_name string
);

insert into units values ('aFsd23j2', 45, 'a');
insert into units values ('aFsd23j2', 34, 'b');
insert into units values ('aFsd23j2', 12, 'c');
insert into units values ('r8cxn23n', 130, 'a');
insert into units values ('r8cxn23n', 139, 'b');
insert into units values ('r8cxn23n', null, 'c');

select *
from units
```

What would be the reason behind that?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, OLAP DB like BigQuery is not optimized for mutating queries (i.e. INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE).
If you reduce the number of insert statements, it will get faster than before.

```sql
create temporary table units (
  id string,
  Nof_units int,
  source_name string
);

insert into units values
('aFsd23j2', 45, 'a'),
('aFsd23j2', 34, 'b'),
('aFsd23j2', 12, 'c'),
('r8cxn23n', 130, 'a'),
('r8cxn23n', 139, 'b'),
('r8cxn23n', null, 'c');

select *
from units;
```

output: 16.9 sec --> 4.4 sec in my environment